# Почему Паскаль не считывает несколько переменных разных типов данных в одной строке read?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
    program calc;
var a, b: real;
    z: char;
begin
  readln(a, b);
  readln(z);
  if z = '+' then
    writeln('a + b = ', a + b)
  else
    if z = '-' then
      writeln('a - b = ', a - b)
    else
      if z = '*' then
        writeln('a * b = ', a * b)
      else
        if z = '/' then
          writeln('a / b = ', a / b)
        else
          writeln('Не удалось решить')
end.
```

Почему Паскаль не может считывать переменные в одной строке read с разными типами данных? Один человек с помощью бота пишет, что потому, что программа ожидает, что пользователь введет в одну строку - один тип данных, а в другую - другую, таким образом для типа данных real своя строка считывания, для char - другая. А другой пишет, задавая вопрос, кто такую глупость сказал, прикрепляя скриншот с переменными целочисленного типа и строкового. Ради интереса, код обычного калькулятора написан. В интернете были коды, причем отмечены как лучше, но у меня они даже запускаться почему-то не хотели, но дело не в этом.
И если все переменные в одной строке read, то не дает ввести значение переменной z, а если же как в коде, в разных строках, то всё работает. Ну я и в общем, не пойму, что не так...

Comment: вводите строку и разбивайте её на токены. А считывать разные данные, разделенный пробелом, read умеет (в вашем pascalabc не проверял, но он же должен обеспечивать совместимоcть?)

Comment: @MBo что вы имеете ввиду? Чтобы значения всех этих переменных можно было ввести, включая переменную z, приходится вводить её дважды readln(a, b, z, z);

Comment: Delphi https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JKDa.png  Однако истинный путь указан в первом предложении